# error "object ‘coef.cv.glmnet’ is not exported by 'namespace:glmnet' " while loading Lime package in R -

Tags: r, lime

I've successfully installed Lime (and glmnet) in R but when I try loading it i receive an error:

```
> require(lime)
Loading required package: lime
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lime’:
 object ‘coef.cv.glmnet’ is not exported by 'namespace:glmnet'
```

Searched online and can't seem to find a solution for this.
This is my sessioninfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] glmnet_3.0    Matrix_1.2-17

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       rstudioapi_0.10  magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 lattice_0.20-38  R6_2.4.0         rlang_0.4.1     
[10] foreach_1.4.7    dplyr_0.8.3      tools_3.6.1      grid_3.6.1       gtable_0.3.0     iterators_1.0.12 lazyeval_0.2.2   assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3    
[19] crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.3      ggplot2_3.2.1    codetools_0.2-16 shape_1.4.4      glue_1.3.1       compiler_3.6.1   pillar_1.4.2     scales_1.0.0    
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

I've updated all my packages.
glmnet loads successfully

```
> library(glmnet)
Loaded glmnet 3.0
```

Comment: I was getting the same error as you, but then I uninstalled the glmnet package and lime package, and then reinstalled both. With glmnet 3.0-2, and lime 0.5.1, I do not get this error any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent major update of glmnet (which now does not export `coef.cv.glmnet` anymore) appears to have broken lime. You can see errors with the same cause in the [CRAN tests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_lime.html). You can expect a fix by the package maintainer soon (or the package will be archived by CRAN). See also [this bug report and the answer by the maintainer](https://github.com/thomasp85/lime/issues/168):

> This is due to a recent breaking change in glmnet—lime will be updated soon to fix this